# How to filter the groupby dataframe in a multiindexed data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
ID  Group   Score1
1     A       45       
2     A       12
3     B       33
3     C       64
.     .       .
.     .       .
15000 .       .
```

There are thousands of IDs that are repeated and 15 groups in total.
For every group, I want to display

1. Number of unique IDs greater than or equal to Median Score
2. Number of unique IDs greater than Score 40
3. Number of unique IDs below the first quartile(0-25th percentile range) of the Score column
4. Number of unique IDs above the third quartile(75 - 100th percentile range) of the Score column

So my output looks like this:
Output:

```
Group  No of unique  No of unique  No of unique      No of unique
      IDs >= Median  IDs > 40       IDs below         IDs above the
                                  first quartile      third quartile
 A         56           25             17                 45
 B         33           78             28                 62
 C         23           36             38                 33
 .
 .
 P         39           28             26                 41
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works. First I created the four corresponding columns first in the original dataframe. Then create `df1` which is the dataframe `df` with unique ID's. Finally, using `pd.groupby()` you can create the desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(range(100)),
                   'Group': list('ABCDE')*20,
                   'Score1': np.random.randint(10, 99, 100)})

df['No of unique IDs >= Median'] = df.Score1 >= df.groupby('Group').Score1.transform('median')
df['No of unique IDs > 40'] = df.Score1 > 40
df['No of unique IDs < first quartile'] = df.Score1 < df.groupby('Group').Score1.transform(lambda x: np.quantile(x, q=0.25))
df['No of unique IDs > third quartile'] = df.Score1 > df.groupby('Group').Score1.transform(lambda x: np.quantile(x, q=0.75))

df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Group']).any().reset_index()

df1.groupby('Group').agg({'No of unique IDs >= Median': 'sum',
                          'No of unique IDs > 40': 'sum',
                          'No of unique IDs < first quartile': 'sum',
                          'No of unique IDs > third quartile': 'sum'})
```

Comment: @T C Molenaar, Thanks for your response.
From your answer, even if I don't apply this step 
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Group']).any().reset_index(), 
I am getting the same result.
How do we ensure that we are counting the sum of unique IDs for every column?

Comment: I do get different results with my dummy example, did you change `df1` into `df`?

Comment: @T C Molenaar, Yes it worked. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Molenaar, I think there is problem with the logic. 
In the line df['No of unique IDs >= Median'] = df.Score1 >= df.Score1.median(), 
we are filtering the column by values greater than median of entire column.
But we have to filter them by median broken down by group and the median for every group varies.
Can you suggest me with this?

Comment: @Yash You are right, I updated my answer, also for the quantiles

Comment: Thanks @T C Molenaar